# How to return from tmux '?' hotkeys ("help") window

Tags: tmux

I have some valuable output in my tmux pane, after which I have pressed ctrl-B + ?, opening list of tmux hotkeys. I need to return to the original view of this tmux session. How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just copy mode, q or C-c, or Escape as well with emacs keys.

Comment: Tried all 3 hotkeys, all work. I guess my confusion was coming from prepending them with the prefix (C-b).